# Using Knockout.js with newest jQuery Files and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I am attempting to use Knockout.js with ASP.NET MVC 3.0 (Title gave it away, didn't it?!)

http://knockout.js.com

I am running into some problems (more related to the new jQuery Tmpl Engine than ASP.NET MVC 3.0).

I am using Steve Sanderson's Example Program in my test, and have **mostly** replicated his results with the new Razor View Engine (I do not believe Razor has anything to do with my problem).

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/07/12/editing-a-variable-length-list-knockout-style/

However I want to do more with the **natural** jquery binding, instead of the HTML binding attributes. This is described in detail on knockout's tutorial. 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

However I am unable to reproduce this as it explains. I will show below my View Code. My problem is coming from the fact that `{{foreach (i, gift) gifts}}` doesn't work. I have tried many variants ( `{{foreach (i, gift) gifts()}}` as I have seen in other examples).

I am using the **latest** `knockout.js` file. I am using `jQuery 1.4.3.` I am using `http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js` for templating engine. However, I have also tried this using the same `tmpl.js` file that is included on knockous.js's website, and I get the same results.

> When using jQuery Templating, Per the current specification, the template does not render.

The jQuery Template Tags Documentation is found Here : http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/template-tags/

In case anyone was confused about my exact model. If I replace `{{foreach (i, gift) gifts}}` with {`{foreach gift}}`, then the model renders and behaves correctly, but I cannot use the jQuery native `${property}` declarations for anything.

### HTML

```
@model IEnumerable<Knockout.GiftModel>
@using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

@{
    View.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Site.cshtml";
}

    <h2>Gift list editor</h2>

    <form class="giftListEditor" action="/home/index" method="post" >
        <table> 
            <tbody data-bind="template:'giftRowTemplate'"></tbody> 
        </table>

        <button data-bind="click: addGift">Add Gift</button>
        <button data-bind="enable: gifts().length > 0" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/html" id="giftRowTemplate">
        {{each (i, gift) gifts}}
        <tr> 
            <td>Gift name: <input class="required" data-bind="value: Title, uniqueName: true" /> ${Title} </td> 
            <td>Price: $ <input class="required number" data-bind="value: Price, uniqueName: true"/></td> 
            <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeGift( $value ) }">Delete</a></td> 
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var initialData = @(new HtmlString(Model.ToJson()));
        var viewModel = {
            gifts: ko.observableArray(initialData),
            addGift: function () {
                this.gifts.push({ Title: "", Price: "" });
            },

            removeGift: function (gift) {
                this.gifts.remove(gift);
            },

            save: function () {
                ko.utils.postJson(location.href, { gifts: this.gifts });
            }
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $("form").validate({ submitHandler: function() { viewModel.save() } });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would approach this differently. I would use the following line:

```
<tbody data-bind='template: { name: "giftRowTemplate", foreach: gifts }'></tbody>
```

instead of:

```
<tbody data-bind="template:'giftRowTemplate'"></tbody>
```

That way you dont need to use the `{{each (i, gift) gifts}}` line in the template that is giving you trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just had some typos and didn't match up with what you were explaining. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`{{each  gifts}}` instead of `{{each (i, gift) gifts}}` will do the trick.